# access parent function inside module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

Helo, My problem with this code is that i can not access checkIf to set its property LengthIs, and when i log if `this` is equal or not to `module.exports`, it logs `false`. I also logged this and it gave me some big object and i could not get what was it, maybe it was `global`. So what is the problem?

```
module.exports = {
    checkIf: function(field){
        console.log(this === module.exports)
        this.checkIf.LengthIs = function(params){
            return function(req,res,next){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([named-function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)):

```
module.exports = {
    checkIf: function checkIf(field){
        checkIf.LengthIs = function(params){
            return function(req,res,next){
        }
    }
}
```

In case you want to use the method as providing an argument and getting back custom check methods tailored to that initial argument you can try sth like the following:

```
module.exports = {
    checkIf: function checkIf(field){
        return {
          LengthIs: function(params){
              // use "field" parameter somewhere in this method 
              return function(req,res,next){/* whatever.. */ };
          }/*,
          .. possibly other methods as well */
        };
     }
}
```

Then you can do:

`this.checkIf("email").LengthIs(xx);` and so on..

Comment: it solved the problem but, when i use checkif as middleware and try to access LengthIs is returns undefined like this: checkIf.LengthIs and also like this: checkIf('email').LengthIs()

Comment: The way it is written, it needs to be called first before lengthIs function is added to checkIf

Comment: Can you be more concrete

Comment: Please update your question with the exact problem you have so I can be more speciific. But it is simpl;e lengthIs property is added to checkIf function every time it is called, so initialy checkIf.lengthIs is indeed undefined, it needs to be called first. Else define the property in another manner to be always there

Comment: I just thought that checkIf('email') called it and i could be able to access Lengthis

Comment: No as it is written, you have to wait for **call to finish and then access it**. Why do you do it so confusing?

Comment: @iLiA, updateed answer with another approach that may suit you better, your initial approach (if I understand correctly) is convoluted and does not result in what you have in mind as use case. try this as well